# Duplicate rows returned even though group by is used

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, sql-order-by

This is my query

```
SELECT p.book FROM customers_books p 
INNER JOIN books b ON p.book = b.id 
INNER JOIN bookprices bp ON bp.book = p.book 
WHERE b.status = 'PUBLISHED' AND bp.currency_code = 'GBP' 
AND p.book NOT IN (SELECT cb.book FROM customers_books cb WHERE cb.customer = 1) 
GROUP BY p.book, p.created_date ORDER BY p.created_date DESC
```

This is the data in my customers_books table,
[image]

I expect only 8,6,1 of books IDs to return but query is returning 8,6,1,1

table structures are here

```
CREATE TABLE "public"."customers_books" (
  "id" int8 NOT NULL,
  "created_date" timestamp(6),
  "book" int8,
  "customer" int8,
);

CREATE TABLE "public"."books" (
  "id" int8 NOT NULL,
  "created_date" timestamp(6),
  "status" varchar(255) COLLATE "pg_catalog"."default",
)

CREATE TABLE "public"."bookprices" (
  "id" int8 NOT NULL,
  "currency_code" varchar(255) COLLATE "pg_catalog"."default",
  "book" int8
)
```

what do you think I am doing wrong here.
I really dont want to use `p.created_date` in `group by` but I was forced to use because of `order by`

Comment: Change your query to `select p.book, p.created_date` leaving the rest unchanged.  Run it, and you should see right away.

Comment: Since you're grouping by `(book, created_date)` you are creating 2 groups for book 1 (one for 24/06/2020 & another for 27/06/2020). Maybe you want `GROUP BY book ORDER BY MAX(created_date) DESC`?

Comment: @Marth that worked, great. Could you explain a little bit more why it worked. thanks

Comment: and also is there a better way to write this query

Comment: @Eric: You could rewrite it using `WHERE EXISTS` instead, it might be faster and easier to understand. I would also advise against using `NOT IN`, especially when the column is nullable. One thing I don't understand about your query is why you want to `ORDER BY created_date` when you're only fetching `book` (which is always the same whatever the date ordering).

Comment: @Marth I need order by to know the recent purchased books. Could you write me a WHERE EXISTS query for me please without NOT IN if thats okay ? thanks

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT p.book or simply avoid group by date and the order by.

Comment: As said also, in terms of performance/quality, do not use "NOT IN", instead, joins with where conditions or even ANTI JOIN should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have too many joins in the outer query:

```
SELECT b.book
FROM books b INNER JOIN
     bookprices bp
     ON bp.book = p.book 
WHERE b.status = 'PUBLISHED' AND bp.currency_code = 'GBP' AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM customers_books cb
                  WHERE cb.book = p.book AND cb.customer = 1
                 ) ;
```

Note that I replaced the `NOT IN` with `NOT EXISTS`.  I strongly, strongly discourage you from using `NOT IN` with a subquery.  If the subquery returns *any* `NULL` values, then `NOT IN` returns no rows at all.  It is better to sidestep this issue just by using `NOT EXISTS`.